# Javascript: wierd RegExp behaviour

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I receive as result:

```
_a_b_|_c_d_
```

when using the following code/regexp:

```
var separator = "|";
var ex = new RegExp(separator,"g");
var result = "ab|cd".replace(ex, "_");

console.log(result);
```

**Why does it behave like that?**

I expect (and want) to only replace all pipes in a string:

```
ab_cd
```

Answer (score 3):

You should escape the `|` symbol in your regex, so that it would match a literal `|` symbol. In regex `|` called logical OR operator which was usually used to combine or OR two regexes.

**What's the reason for getting `_a_b_|_c_d_` as output?**

I already said that `|` is called logical OR operator. It's syntax would be like `regex1|regex2|regex3|regex4.......` and so on. But in your case `|`, there isn't a pattern before and after to the OR (`|`) operator. So it does a zero width match before and after to each and every character. Replacing the zero width match with `_` will give you `_a_b_|_c_d_` as result.

```
> var separator = "\\|";
undefined
> var ex = new RegExp(separator,"g");
undefined
> var result = "ab|cd".replace(ex, "_");
undefined
> console.log(result);
ab_cd
```

**OR**

```
> var separator = /\|/g;
undefined
> var ex = new RegExp(separator);
undefined
> var result = "ab|cd".replace(ex, "_")
undefined
> console.log(result);
ab_cd
```

Comment: this seems the point, but "var separator = "\|";" doesn't work.

Comment: +1 that's it - i just wonder why i do have to use two backslashes

Comment: Because of the pattern was included within `""`. You don't need to escape the backslash one more time if it is given inside the `/` symbols.

Comment: ok, thx - that's it (didn't think of the OR logic here - stupid me)

Comment: is it only in javascript ? at other place single \ works

Comment: @vks In js you can give the pattern inside `//` also .

Comment: var separator = "/\|/";

Comment: @Thariama no, it would be `var separator = /\|/g;` . Remove the double quotes. `"`, `/` called delimiters.

Comment: @Thariama added an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var separator = "\\|";
var ex = new RegExp(separator,"g");
var result = "ab|cd".replace(ex, "_");

console.log(result);
alert(result);
```

Because in Regex there is a special meaning for | [or].

Please refer to this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-classes) to understand the meaning for each special characters in Regex which needs to escaped with \

Hope this helps.